# (vs2015)I can link to server in debug mode,but when I use release mode,it can't work

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, release

```
Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
```

When I run the code in debug mode.It works well and I can get information from server.But when I use release mode, it crashes.

> The warning infomation: An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to connect to the remote server

Comment: How do you create the request? Do you have different app.config/web.config files based on build configuration?

Comment: @cremor I solved this problem by closing firewall, now it runs well in release mode. Anyway, thanks a lot!